# What is need to do with invalid runtimeconfig.json Azure app service

Tags: azure, asp.net-core

I'm trying out Azure (App Service) for the first time and I am trying to publish my ASP.NET Core 3.0 project. I've published to Azure using Visual Studio 2019 and all files copied but I keep getting the error in the logs folder:

Invalid runtimeconfig.json

I've read some Stackoverflow questions about it but most of them don't apply to my scenario. Can somebody help out please?

Comment: Is there any other information, other than `invalid runtimeconfig.json` and is this a file that you have published? Also check to make sure everything is okay in Kudu: https://YOUR_SITE_NAME.scm.azurewebsites.net/

Answer (score 3):

In my case I made below changes for aspNetCore in web.config:

> from **stdoutLogFile="\?%home%\LogFiles\stdout"** to
> **stdoutLogFile=".\LogFiles\stdout"**

That's why problem was showing. but please keep **stdoutLogFile="\?%home%\LogFiles\stdout** as it is.

Here is the complete web.config

```
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\SmartApp.Inventory.Api.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile="\\?\%home%\LogFiles\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer this post from [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/AZURE/comments/bayr7k/aspnet_core_22_on_azure_app_service/) and from [`stack overflow`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44782616/invalid-runtimeconfig-json-error-when-trying-to-run-netcore-app-on-linux),

> Open kudu on the app service in the portal and try to start the
> service. This should give a better error.
>
> I had an issue when 2.2 first came out where it was not deployed to
> one of the azure regions I was using but 2.2 should be out everywhere
> now